# Obtaining time stamps from UIbutton clicks and using them to calculate time difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsdateformatter

I am not finding anything that specifically addresses this question via search, so here goes...

I am creating a calculator that uses start time and stop time as an element. There is a start button. When clicked, it grabs the current time and updates a label next to it with the grabbed time stamp in hh:mm:ss:SS format. Same with the stop time button.

What I need to do is be able to access those start and stop times for the purposes of subtracting the start time from the stop time and thus getting the time elapsed to use in a larger calculation.

This seems like an easy fix for someone that knows a lot more about this than I. I have been through the Date & Time Programming Guide documentation, and it addresses other types of calculations, but not this one.

Here is my implementation code for the start and stop buttons:

```
     // startButton action - grabs start time and updates startTimeLabel
    - (IBAction)startButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss.SS"];
        _startTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        UIButton *startButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        startButton.enabled = NO;
        stop.enabled = YES;
    }

    // stopButton action - grabs start time and updates stopTimeLabel, enables 
    calculate and resume buttons
    - (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss.SS"];
        _stopTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        UIButton *stopButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        stopButton.enabled = NO;
        calculate.enabled = YES;
        // Hides keypad on calculateButton click
        [self.startLevel resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Here are the IBActions and Outlets for the start and stop buttons from the header file:

```
    // ACTION for startButton. Grabs current time.
    // NEED TO DETERMINE HOW TO PUT THAT TIME IN THE CALCULATION
    - (IBAction)startButton:(UIButton *)sender;
    // OUTLET for startButton. Allows button state to be initialized.
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *start;


    // ACTION for stopButton. Grabs current time.
    // NEED TO DETERMINE HOW TO PUT THAT TIME IN THE CALCULATION
    - (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender;
    // OUTLET for stopButton. Allows button state to be initialized.
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stop;
```

Thanks for your help, folks.

Comment: Why the downvote? Was this answered elsewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882410/calculate-time-elapsed-between-pressing-the-same-button-twice?rq=1

Comment: Yeah that's not exactly what I was looking for but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Save the start date and the stop date to ivars.

In the stop action (or calculate action, why an extra action?) calculate the difference with `[stopDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];`

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeElapsedLabel;
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSDate *startDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSDate *stopDate;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    [self.startButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.stopButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    self.timeElapsedLabel.text = @"";
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    [self.stopButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    self.stopDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.startButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    self.timeElapsedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [self.stopDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, save NSDates as instance variables. Don't convert to strings using date formatters.

For that matter you could save NSTimeIntervals:

Header:

```
@interface MyVC
{
  NSTimeInterval startTime;
  NSTimeInterval endTime;
}
@end
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
  startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}

- (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
  endTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
  NSTimeInterval elapsedSeconds = endTime - startTime;
  NSLog(@"It has been %.2f seconds since you clicked the start button");
}
```

I'll leave updating your start and stop time and elapsed time labels to you.

Comment: Duncan - you're a young boss. Thanks very much. I am sorry if this was a stupid question. I am doing the best with what I have learned so far. I am going to go code this right now. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Don't declare the ivars in the .h file. Do it in the .m file.

Comment: I declared them in the .h file and it seems to be working. Is there some advantage to declaring in the implementation?

Comment: @Maddy, do you mean using an anonymous category, to make the iVars semi-private? That is a matter of style. I don't like it, because it means the iVars are not visible to subclasses. I follow the rule that iVars are ALL protected, and make properties for things I want to share with outside classes.

Comment: There are several advantages to declaring ivars in the .m instead of the .h. 1) The world shouldn't know or care about your implementation details. The .h should only have public info. 2) Minimizing what is in  the .h cuts down on compile times as you add or change ivars and other private details. @DuncanC Personally ivars should NOT be visible to subclasses. It breaks encapsulation and makes your code much more fragile. Notice how Apple doesn't expose any ivars to us. They are private for a reason. And use `@implementaiton { // ivars here }` or a class extension.